# The use of 'as a cosmetic'

Tags: phrase-usage

I have found a sentence on line. I'm confused with the use of the word 'cosmetic' in the sentence. In a dictionary, it is described as a noun (usually plural) and an adjective. Please explain it to me whether the use of 'cosmetic' in the sentence is correct or not.

> Rice starch or rice powder has been used as a cosmetic for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The word is usually used in the plural, that is because most "make-up" is a mixture of substances, and when using make-up most people will use several types (foundation, blusher, lipstick etc)

The use of the singular is rarer, it refers to a single substance that improves the appearance of your face. In this example, rice starch is a cosmetic, and is among the oldest cosmetics.

Comment: Use of the singular is common in pharmaceutical circles. I suffer from dry skin, and had been prescribed a proprietary moisturising cream by my doctor. I am aged over 60 and therefore, in the UK, get free prescription medicines. I recently had a letter from my local health authority saying they had re-classified Johnson & Johnson's Aveeno Cream as 'a cosmetic' and were substituting another, generic, product.

Comment: I also hear the singular used quite often.